# Using includes with AREL functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I have the following classes in my application:

```
class Prompt
  has_many :entries
end

class Entry
  belongs_to :prompt
  belongs_to :user

  def self.approved
    where("is_approved")
  end
end

class User
  has_many :entries
end
```

And I want to display a table of all "approved" entries for a given prompt and the users that they `belong_to`. To generate this list I do the following query:

`prompt = Prompt.find(prompt_id, :include => {:entries => :user})`

But when I run the following loop, it makes a query for each user rather than using the prefetched users

```
prompt.entries.approved.each do |entry|
   puts entry.user.id
end
```

How do I rewrite this so that it doesn't do a query for each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

It does a query for each user because *entries.approved* is calling the query *where('is_approved')* for each entry.  Your find statement is merely pulling all of the prompts and creating objects with access to their child attributes.  I think what you need is a where statement that selects all of the entries that have the attribute 'is_approved' and then run through a loop printing their ids.

Maybe try something like @entries = Entry.where(is_approved: true).includes(entries: user) )

Then

entries.user.each do |user|
   puts user.id
end

Hope thats helps.

Comment: Is there a way I can encapsulate that `approved` logic into a function? Also, how would you write it so that the result is a `Prompt` object with everything eagerly loaded

Comment: Hmm as far as I can figure out belongs_to/has_many wont eagerly load the other way around, but with  @entries = Entry.where(is_approved: true)  you should be able to access the eagerly loaded associated prompt by 
entries.prompt.each do |prompt|. 
Sorry